# Azure VM - turning it on and off automatically

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks

I currently have an azure VM (Windows server 2012) at the moment and all it does is run a batch process once a day for about an hour. The rest of the time it's just sitting idle.

As I pay for every hour the VM is on, I'm paying 24 times as much as I need to. Is it possible to set it up so that it only turns itself on for a couple of hours a day.

Maybe either a set time it turns on and off or a set time to turn on and then if it's idle for longer than a set period to turn itself off?

Answer (score 1):

A VM can't turn itself on; you'd need to do this external to the VM(s) in question. It's easy to do via PowerShell (`Start-AzureVM`) or cross-platform CLI (`azure vm start`). Similar commands to stop a VM.

To do this on a scheduled basis, you'd either need to set up your own timer somewhere, or use something like the [Azure Scheduler](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/scheduler/).